# What would cause a rare lchown() failure: Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, symlink, nfs

I have a test of C++ code that in most runs passes, but in some rare instances fails due to the call to lchown() in my application under test, failing with errno EPERM and strerror:

```
Operation not permitted.
```

The code in question in my application is like this:

```
::lchown("pathnameToFile", uid_t(500), static_cast<unsigned>(-1)); // This line works
::lchown("pathnameToFile", static_cast<unsigned>(-1), gid_t(500)); // This fails rarely
```

Also in the test case iteration that failed, the prior attempt to create a symbolic link to the "pathnameToFile" also failed to create it in my application, but the code did not detect any error (the following returned 0):

```
::symlink("pathnameToFile", "linkToPathname");
```

I imagine these two things are related. This is running on a 32 bit Centos 4 machine.

The "pathnameToFile" exists on an NFS mounted partition.  Could there be some kind of race condition between the file being created and the link to it and lchown failing because the NFS does not reflect its existence yet?

After some time elapsed however, the symbolic link appeared although the chown remained without effect.

The "pathnameToFile" lives in a directory with permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 me me   4096 Jun 22 17:33 .
-rw-rw-r--   1 me root   33 Jun 22 17:33 pathnameToFile
lrwxrwxrwx   1 me root    8 Jun 22 17:33 LinkToPathname -> pathnameToFile
```

The gid 500 is the primary group for 'me', the other group being 'wheel'.

```
> groups
me wheel
```

Comment: What is the permission and ownership of the directory the link is in?

Comment: Is `gid 500` in your user's supplementary groups list?

Comment: @samold Not sure if I answered your question?

Comment: Yep - seems like a race condition between your code and NFS. I presume that when you say 'symlink returns 0, but failed' you meant to say that your test code could not verify the existence of the link. That to me implies that NFS is yet to catch up on effecting the changes to its data structures, and the lchown will fail subsequently.

I am not sure if this is an answer you are looking for. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, the symlink appeared to be missing at first and a call to lchown() failed on it with EPERM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a race condition, add a short sleep when the lchown fails and try again.